# ¿Cómo puedo abrir este tipo de archivos de una aplicación android?

Tags: android, android-studio

Decompilé una aplicación con apktool y la estoy revisando para poder jugar con los archivos, pero hay muchos que tienen la terminación .bin.mid y no tengo idea de cómo abrirlos sin que se vean de la siguiente manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Se ve de esa manera porque es un archivo binario, no hay mucho texto que puedas leer. O en otro posible caso está encriptado. Sin más información es difícil ayudarte. Tampoco es moralmente correcto hacer ingeniería inversa.

Comment: Podrías deducir qué archivo es de acuerdo al propósito de la aplicación y la carpeta en la que se encuentra.

Comment: Muchas gracias por el tiempo de leer y por tu respuesta :)